# Ruby: String to Array

Tags: ruby

How would you convert a string to an array in Ruby?

What I want to do is convert a string like `"[value1, value2, value3]"` to an array `[value1, value2, value3]`. Keep in mind some of these values may be strings themselves.

I am trying to write it in a method called `str_to_ary`.

```rb
def str_to_ary
  @to_convert = self
  #however everything I try beyond this point fails
end
```

Comment: Could you use some example values instead of `value1, value2, value3`? As is the question looks a bit ambiguous. It can be easily interpreted that they can be local variables defined beforehand, in which case this will require some eval black magic.

Comment: You wish to convert a string to an array containing `value1`, `value2` and `value3`. Presumably those are local variables or methods (not literals). Is that what you intend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, that looks like a JSON.

```
require 'json'

def str_to_ary
  JSON.parse(@to_convert)
end
```

Note that this is true and works only if those string values in there are between double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: That worked just as intended. I appreciate the help. :)

Comment: Great, glad to hear that :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark as accepted answers that solved your problem. This helps others find solutions that work.

Comment: The string the OP posted is not valid JSON. An array must contain an array, an object, a number, a string, or other primitive type. `value1` is neither of those things, therefore the string is not valid JSON and cannot be parsed as JSON.

Comment: @JörgWMittag those `value1` etc are numbers or strings

Comment: Not according to the JSON spec. Strings must be enclosed in double quotes, so they are not strings, and they aren't numbers either.

Comment: But that's just how the OP put them down. But he even said that those are numbers or strings. Strings in double quotes.

Comment: The only reference I see to the contents of the variables (or return values of the methods) is, "...some of these values may be strings themselves.", which is not the same as "...he even said those were numbers or strings." The question is unclear, and the OP has not responded to questions that ask for clarification. In providing answers all one can do is state assumptions one has made.

Answer (score 1):

well if you know that `[` is always on the first place and `]` is always on the last place then you can start with

```
string = "[X, 1, Test, 22, 3]"
trimmed = string[1,string.length-2]
array = trimmed.split(", ")

array => ["X", " 1", " Test", " 22", " 3"]
```

if you want to then cast 1, 22 or 3 into Integers then that's a different problem that requires more thought. What values are you expecting to have in the array?

Comment: split on `", "` to get rid of the spaces

Comment: Simple parsers like this inevitably end up with tons of corner cases (missing values, mangled values, crashes). Best to stick with a standard parser like json if you know the format fits

Comment: Based on the OP's example, `"[X, 1, Test, 22, 3]"` is to be converted to `[X, 1, Test, 22, 3]`, not an array of strings.